# BI dashboard with SQL 2008 R2 (without sharepoint)

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-3.5, dashboard

I need to create a BI dashboard for an existing database on SQL 2008 R2. For this dashboard, I am not allowed to use Sharepoint (the customer doesn't have it). I will be using .NET 3.5.

Questions:

1. Is a data warehouse required for BI features, such as sector analysis? If so, any related tutorial link will be appreciated.
2. Without Sharepoint, do I need another software for the dashboard?
3. Assuming customer has Office 2010 installed in its machines, would Power Pivot be useful for the dashboard?

**Note:** I have been an enterprise desktop apps developer. This will be my first web project. So please correct me if the questions don't make sense at all.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not  write a stored procedure  and use report builder(stand alone tool ) to generate reports and then host in your site.

You do not need sharepoint for the same.

The link for reportbuilder to download is [Click here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=24085)

Comment: I will check that, thanks. Is data warehouse required in any part for this solution?

Comment: No You do not need datawarehouse